# Applications of list decoding

Tags: reference-request, it.information-theory, coding-theory

This is citation from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_decoding:

Algorithms developed for list decoding of several interesting code families have found interesting applications in computational complexity and the field of cryptography. Following is a sample list of applications outside of coding theory:

Construction of hard-core predicates from one-way permutations.

Predicting witnesses for NP-search problems.

Amplifying hardness of Boolean functions.

Average case hardness of permanent of random matrices.

Extractors and Pseudorandom generators.

Efficient traitor tracing.

---

Can you give references about these applications? Thank you.

upd: http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-1-4020-8140-8

Comment: Did anything come up when you typed, say, "efficient traitor tracing" "list decoding" into Google? Do you have access to Math Reviews online (MathSciNet)?